How to select which Work Items to be back synced
I have multiple dev environments in Salesforce DevOps Center used by different project streams. We have a requirement where we dont want to sync all the work items. Current Devops center functionality does not let you choose which Work Item to be back synched.
Is there any workaround for this?
How is a work item identified to be "not in synch" with a Dev Environment?
